# SimpleCursorAdapter : Empty ListView

Tags: android, android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter

I m using an `SimpleCursorAdapter` with `ListFragment`, but the displayed `ListView` is Empty (items without data):

```
    public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
```

...

```
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    // The desired columns to be bound  
    String[] columns = new String[]{"villename"};   
    int to [] = {R.id.tv_ville_secteur};
```

...

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recherhcer, container, false);
        // LOADING CITYS AND SECTEURS
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

//      MatrixCursor matrixCursor= new MatrixCursor(columns);
//      
        Ville[] villes = new Ville[] {new Ville("0","Rabat"),new Ville("1","Casa")};
//      matrixCursor.addRow(villes);
//      
        db.addVille(villes[0]);
        db.addVille(villes[1]);
        db.getAllVilles();
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.fragment_recherhcer,db.getAllVillesAsCursor(),columns,to);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }
```

...

**item_to_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="14">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_ville_secteur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="13"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_ville_secteur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what does this return `db.getAllVillesAsCursor()`

Comment: public List<Ville> getAllVilles()

Comment: then you have misunderstood the constructor's http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Comment: It takes cursor as a param so `db.getAllVillesAsCursor()` should return a cursor. Also you are using a deprecated constructor

Comment: @Raghunandan  yes they return a cursor .. public Cursor getAllVillesAsCursor()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.fragment_recherhcer,db.getAllVillesAsCursor(),columns,to);
```

to

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_to_search,db.getAllVillesAsCursor(),columns,to);
```

cause `TextView` with id `tv_ville_secteur` is in `item_to_search.xml`.

Also

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

> This constructor was deprecated in API level 11. This option is
>   discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the
>   application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even
>   Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use
>   LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

Should not use the above

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
Standard constructor.
```

Comment: @AbdellahSELASSI but do note that the constructor is deprecated

Comment: @AbdellahSELASSI check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html